# Help identifying a potentiometer/resistor like symbol in the I/O stage of a microcontroller

Tags: resistors, schematics, identification, symbol

I'm having difficulties identifying a schematic symbol. I spotted this while going through the STM32L series reference manual on page 172 located [HERE](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/cc/f9/93/b2/f0/82/42/57/CD00240193.pdf/files/CD00240193.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00240193.pdf).

Here is the symbol in question, and the symbol as it appears in the document:

[image: The symbol]

[image: Part of the schematic]

It's obvious that it's some sort of electronically switchable resistor, I'm just uncertain what the proper name for it is. I thought it was a Voltage Controlled Resistor however I've generally seen those in schematics as the actual FET, as opposed to a symbol like this. My searches haven't turned up anything.

I know they're the pullups/pulldowns for the port, I just have never seen that symbol before.

Does anyone recognize this symbol or know what the proper name for it is?

Thanks!

Comment: uC's often have internal "active pullup" which is selected by register for some applications.  Other IC's have have active pullup/down for apps like bi-directional buses with termination or bias to Vdd/2 when idle.  I dont know of any other name than it's function ie. internal optional Pull-up or down R.... or internal switched active termination R's to Vdd/2

Comment: Yeah. I'm familiar with the function they perform, I just haven't seen that symbol before. Was wondering if there was something special about it or it ST just made up something.

Comment: me neither, since it's an internal CPU schematic, we never use it on external schematics since it has no part or ref.des., Symbols evolve as they are invented.  Next maybe a symbol for wireless 3D VR eyeball projector for glasses that replace all smart phones in the next decade.

Answer (score 8):

They're probably intended to represent small transistors operating in the linear region when used as (configurable) pull-ups or pull-downs. True resistors of such high value are expensive (large acreage required) to make in many VLSI digital processes so transistors are used. See [this](http://booksite.elsevier.com/9781558607354/casestudies/06~Chapter_6/Section_6_11.pdf) reference.

Because the effective resistance of such a pull-up/pull-down is not constant and because it can be switched, the symbol represents it more accurately than a simple MOSFET in series with a resistor.

Keep in mind that commercial I/O circuitry that meets ESD and other requirements is generally fairly complex and proprietary and you can be sure that whatever you are seeing is a simplified version. See, for example, [this](http://www.ics.ee.nctu.edu.tw/~mdker/group%20paper%20abstract/2008-09%20Shih-Fun%20Chen.pdf) student thesis.

Comment: Neat, those links are going to make some interesting reading. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

These are just "selective pull-up and pull-down R's" for the I/O port, with no external common symbol name as they are virtual to we as users.

> configured by software in several modes:

- Input floating
- Input pull-up
- Input-pull-down
- Analog Output open-drain with pull-up or pull-down capability
- Output push-pull with pull-up or pull-down capability
- Alternate function push-pull with pull-up or pull-down capability
- Alternate function open-drain with pull-up or pull-down capability

### opinion

AMD guys probably have an acronym for these parts like *puppy R's*  or programmable PullUPDnRegister y's

- PUPDRy[1:0]:

  - Port x configuration bits (y = 0..15)
- These bits are written by software to configure the I/O pull-up or pull-down

  - 00: No pull-up, pull-down
  - 01: Pull-up
  - 10: Pull-down
  - 11: Reserved

Comment: I agree with that. Further down they talk about setting the ports speed with 4 options ranging from "Low Speed" to "Very High". Makes sense to have adjustable pulls to ensure an adequate slew rate.

Comment: i'd just call em pup's and pud's

Comment: @alphasierra Slew rate is separate from pull up/pull down; you don't have to set up a pull to control slew rate. The pull up/pull down resistor values are not configurable.

Comment: By that do you mean they're not user configurable? Off the top of my head it seems like a stronger pull would respond more slowly than a weaker one. There must be a reason they give the option to specify the port's speed. I'm going to do some experimentation to try and figure it out.

Comment: They specify a "light" load internally and no mention of values. But IF they have a speed option that changes the value , I agree a few orders of magnitude for high speed termination, but no values are given in my cursory read.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like they are using a FET as a variable resistor. Lower value would result in faster rise times. NOTE: Symbols on chip schematics are often only functionally indicative of what they do. The actual device can range from what is shown to a whole circuit or even subsystem.

Comment: I'm trying to get some noticable effect in SPICE. I'm pretending the input port is a 1Meg resistor with 10nF of input capacitance (just to make it really bad). I added in a small amount of inductance in series with the signal source to pretend there were actually traces in between. Sweeping the pull resistor from 1k to 1Meg seemed to have little to no effect with a signal that had a 1ns rise time and a 100ns period.

Comment: Match source impedance to input to find Z with a square wave at V/2 result. Low Z source proves nothing.